# How do I move emails from a folder to the inbox in Outlook?

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook

I created a rule that moved emails from a specific person to a folder I set up for that purpose. Now I deleted the rule so all the emails are once again going to the main inbox however I want past emails from that person in the inbox also. I don't know how to delete the folder without deleting all the emails inside it also.

I am using Outlook 2003 on Microsoft Exchange

In general in windows I believe there should be a way to delete a folder and have all its contents simply move into the next location in the file path

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within Outlook you can simply select and drag all of those messages into the desired folder. Once the folder is empty it is safe to delete it. All of this is done within Outlook, not working directly with Windows.

Comment: Thanks. I couldn't figure out how to drag them or to cut and paste. However there is an option to move all selected emails into a different folder which is what I did.

Answer (score 1):

Select first email, scroll to the last email. Press shift and click the last email. Now they're all highlighted and you can drag them into your inbox. Your folder should now be empty and you can delete it.

Comment: Or simply press CTRL+A in the folder to select all.